# SQL Join multiple tables query

Tags: mysql, database, join

Hi I have these 2 problems below and my attempt. Please give me some advice.

**SQL database**:

`CUSTOMER` table: `CUST_ID`, `CUST_NAME`, ...

`PRODUCT` table: `PROD_ID`, `PROD_DESCRIPTION`, ...

`CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` table: `CUST_ID` and `PROD_ID`.

This database is used to track the products a customer owns, so `CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` has an entry for each product a customer owns.

I want to:

**A:**

Write a SQL query that will return a **list of all customers who do not own any products**.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER _PRODUCTS.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS
ON CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CUST_ID != CUSTOMER.CUST_ID;
```

**B:**

Write a SQL query that will return **a list of all customers who own a product with ‘SAW’ in the name**.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER _PRODUCTS.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS
ON CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID and WHERE PROD_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'SAW';
```

What do you guys think? am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: none of them should work

Comment: 2 problems = 2 questions please

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful problems to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For B

```
SELECT CUSTOMER _PRODUCTS.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
   INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS ON CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID 
and WHERE PROD_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SAW%';
```

Other person beat me to part A

Comment: Sorry my first answer add percent sign to the in the beginning and end of the word '%saw%'.

Answer (score 0):

For the **A**, you may want to use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT     CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME
FROM       CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN  CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS ON CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CUST_ID
WHERE      CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CUST_ID IS NULL;
```

for the **B**, pease ask separate question, as it is separate.